# Add element to grandchild collection in MongoDb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I have a MongoDb document like this

```
"schools":
[
    "name" : "University",
    "classes" :
    [
        {
            "name":"Chem",
            "teachers":
                [
                    "Joe",
                    "Bill"
                ]
        },
        {
            "name":"Math",
            "teachers":
                [
                    "Julie",
                    "Phil"
                ]
        },
    ],
    // More schools/classes/teachers here
]
```

How do I add a new teacher to the Math class?

(I'm writing this in node.js)

Comment: *I've tried this, but it's not adding the item.*  Did you mean to add some code here?

Comment: ah, I was going to, and then deleted it. I didn't want to pollute the answer with my obviously wrong try. I forgot to delete the comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the specific case you listed, you can do it like this:

```
myDocument.schools[0].classes[1].teachers.push("A new teacher");
myDocument.save();
```

For general cases (eg, add teacher to a class named "xyz"), you'd have to loop through the appropriate array(s) to find the item you're looking for.